# Taking input, processing it in python code and display output in tables on html page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am quite new to Django and struggling to do something very simple. I want to convert Boolean expressions into truth table using Django framework. I have python code I wanna know how I can connect it in a way that input from html goes to that python code, gets processed and output is displayed in tables on html page.

Answer (score 0):

you have to learn how get and post method works in django , then try to connect your html template in django-views then render the html templates in the views function
you can search on youtube. there is a lot of videos that can help you with that.